# Why large number of fprintf-s takes up all free memory?

Tags: c, linux, out-of-memory

For display my problem i was write a little program, that opened file, writed large number of strings in cycle to it, and close file. After program ends, all of RAM was in use with cached pages, and was no more RAM for use another programs.
It was run on Ubuntu 20.04 and compiled with gcc 9.4.0
Same problem in CentOS 7, 8
Only workaround I find - it force drop cache by command
`# echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches`

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    FILE* f = fopen("/tmp/outfile.txt", "w");
    for (long i = 0; i < 2000000000; i++) {
        fprintf(f, "%s\n", "Test message");
    }
    fclose(f);
}
```

Memory before program start looks like this:
[htop before run program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BjB5Z.png)

After program ends, all RAM in use:
[htop after program end](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LJOgX.png)

What may be wrong in code, or in OS?

Comment: The Linux kernel might not unmap pages from a process directly, and keep a lot of data cached. *But* when another process really need those pages it will release them to be used.  Unused memory is still unused, even it is reported as not free.

Comment: Is /tmp implemented as a `tmpfs`?   Tmpfs is a file system which keeps all of its files in virtual memory.

Comment: @Alexander Slesarenko, with `#include <iostream>`, why tag C instead of C++?  Suggest `#include <iostream>` --> `#include <stdio.h>` and reverify problem with  a C compiler or switch tag to C++.